# Talking hypothetically

Tags: word-choice

What is grammatical?

> I wish you would be more romantic

Or

> I wish you were more romantic

Why?

Comment: Why do you think only one is grammatical? Please explain what you would like to say and we will be more able to help you. Neither of them is particularly hypothetical, so what do you mean in your title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['I wish' and counterfactual](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17270/i-wish-and-counterfactual)

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine grammatically, but I *think* there is at *slight* difference in meaning.

"I wish you were more romantic" means "I wish you were more romantic in your nature, because then you would always buy flowers for my birthday"

"I wish you would be more romantic" means "I wish you would remember that you are supposed to do romantic things like buying flowers for my birthday"

One wish is about who you are, the other is about how you behave.